# take long text from mysqli and display

Tags: php

I'm trying to display some long text from database, but that long text display like this:

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext

I tried to put a width but it still does.
I want like this:

texttexttext

texttexttext

texttexttext

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM jurnal ORDER BY ID DESC";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '            <div class="bgCont">
                    <p>' . $row["title"] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $row["description"] . '</p>
                </div>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: If the `div`'s style has a `width`, try adding: `word-wrap: break-word;` as well.

Comment: This sounds like a HTML question. What does it have to do with mysqli? Please do not mix PHP and HTML. You should first prepare the data and then display it in HTML. Don't put mysqli logic between your presentation logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either with php or CSS like

```
<?php
    $str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
    $len = 30;

    $array = wordwrap($str, $len, "<br>");
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Where $str is the long text and $len is a number of characters to wrap the string on.

Also you can do it with CSS by adding this rule into div

```
div.bgCont {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```